# webpack dev server with razor templating engine (angular2 - netcore)

Tags: angularjs, razor, webpack, asp.net-core, webpack-dev-server

I have a aspnet core + angular2 + webpack project. I´m having trouble to get working the livereload part of webpack-dev-server. I think the problem may come because the use of razor templating. Dev server expects a plain index.html that never exists.

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
var CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
entry: {
    polyfills: './wwwroot/polyfills.ts',
    vendor: './wwwroot/vendor.ts',
    app: "./wwwroot/main.ts"

},
output: {
    publicPath : '/lib/webpack',
    path:'wwwroot/lib/webpack',
    filename: '[name].[hash].build.js'
},

resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
},

devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, '/wwwroot/'),
    proxy: {
        '*': 'http://localhost:5000'
    },
    watchOptions: {
        aggregateTimeout: 300,
        poll: 1000
    }
},

module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.ts$/,
            loaders: ['ts-loader?ConfigFileName=./wwwroot/tsconfig.json', 'angular2-template-loader']

        },
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            loaders: 'style-loader!css-loader'
        },
        {
            test: /\.woff($|\?)|\.woff2($|\?)|\.ttf($|\?)|\.eot($|\?)|\.svg($|\?)/,
            loader: 'url-loader'
        },
        {
            test: /\.(html)$/,
            loader: 'raw-loader'
        }
    ]
},

plugins: [

    new CleanWebpackPlugin(
        [
            './wwwroot/lib/webpack'
        ]
    ),

    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        jQuery: 'jquery',
        $: 'jquery',
        jquery: 'jquery'
    }),

    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
        name: ['app', 'vendor', 'polyfills']
    }),

    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        inject: false,
        template: 'Views/Shared/_layoutTemplate.cshtml',
        filename: '../../../Views/Shared/_layout.cshtml'
    }),
]
```

}

The dev server runs and then I run the dotnet project. The result is that I can render the page because of the proxy. But the dev server does not inject it´s livereload code in that rendered view. So when I do changes i have to reload manually.

How can I tell dev server to use that .cshtml file? or how can I achieve it?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you looked at [SPA Templates](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/02/14/building-single-page-applications-on-asp-net-core-with-javascriptservices/) from Microsoft? They provide already working template with Angular 2, ASP.NET Core and Webpack that works together out of the box.